# Is there a way to access "this" in Frida?

Tags: frida

Let's say I have the following hook:

```
Java.perform(function() {
     var test = Java.use('hello.world');
     test.test2.overload('int').implementation = function(arg0) {
          console.log(this);
     return this.test(arg0);
}
```

It gives me

> {$handle: '0x2345', '$weakRef': 283}

But I know it has a field that I want to access.

How do I access this?

Answer (score 0):

`Java.cast(this, Java.use('com.whatever.class')).fieldName.value`

You can also get class name from `.$className`